# AngularJS after select show 2 values

Tags: angularjs, select, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to make a selectbox where i can select a name, after i selected the name i have to show 2 values, the **dateOfBirth** and dateOfBirth with the filter so you can see the age (for example 19 years old)

But my problem is that it shows all the values from dateOfBirth.

For better understanding watch this: http://jsfiddle.net/9obhfm5c/1/

Template:

```
<div  ng-app="mainApp">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        the birthday of
        <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect">
              <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.dateOfBirth}}">
                  {{option.vn}}
             </option>
        </select>
      is {{data.repeatSelect}} and is <span ng-model="data.repeatSelect" ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions | filter:data.repeatSelect">{{ option.dateOfBirth | ageFilter }}</span> years old
      <br/><br/>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = {
    repeatSelect: null,
    availableOptions: [
      {vn:'Mike', an:'Johnson', dateOfBirth: '1996-03-11'},
      {vn:'Curry', an:'Muisjes', dateOfBirth: '1992-03-11'},
      {vn:'Jan', an:'Peters', dateOfBirth: '1995-03-11'}
    ],
    };
}]);
mainApp.filter('ageFilter', function () {
        function calculateAge (birthday) {
            var date = new Date(birthday);
            var ageDifMs = Date.now() - date.getTime();
            var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
            return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
        }

        return function (birthdate) {
            return calculateAge(birthdate);
        };
    });
```

You can see that it outputs all the years (192320) and when you select 1 name it displays a proper value, but i want it first to be emptied and after the select that it shows the age.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's good for you, but you can hide the  while nothing is selected.

You can do this by adding ng-show="data.repeatSelect != null".

http://jsfiddle.net/arielcessario/9hfvkL32/

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        the birthday of
        <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect">
              <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.dateOfBirth}}">
                  {{option.vn}}
             </option>
        </select>
      is {{data.repeatSelect}} and is <span **ng-show="data.repeatSelect != null"** ng-model="data.repeatSelect" ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions | filter:data.repeatSelect">{{ option.dateOfBirth | ageFilter }}</span> years old
      <br/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx man! If nobody gives another answer i can use this as an solution!!

Comment: No problem! One question, you are using the filter for some reason or just is for practice? Regards!

Comment: Nice! If you don't mind, I've modified the original code to apply some stuff related to the angular way. https://jsfiddle.net/arielcessario/2g89x1op/1/. The result is the same, but look at ng-options and the way the controller is used instead of $scope (http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/). And If you want some good reading about angular, try john papa's blog. Regards!!